# Undefined name 'http' in FLUTTER even after restarting the IDE

Tags: http, flutter, dependencies

im new to flutter,i tried to use **http** dependency in my App,The steps are followed as,

1.imported in pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  http: ^0.12.1
```

2)Then i run the, >flutter pub get,command,

3. Then i imported the package in my dart code as ,

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  var url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos";

  // Used to initialize something before starting of the screen
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    fetchdata();
  }

  fetchdata() async {
    var res = await http.get(url);
    print(res);
  }
```

As you can see from the below code,I want to get the response from the URL and want to print the response,i even restarted my IDE after this several times,but it didnt show up,the error message is ,

> compiler message:  lib/pages/home_page.dart:22:21: Error: The getter
> 'http' isn't defined for the class '_HomepageState'.
>
> - '_HomepageState' is from 'package:first_app/pages/home_page.dart' ('lib/pages/home_page.dart').  Try correcting the name to the name of
>   an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'http'.
>   var res = await http.get(url);

This is just a simple error i know,but it'll be a great help for me,Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 37):

Change

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

instead of

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';
```

in your dart code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Paste the below code in *pubspec.yaml*

   ```yaml
   dependencies:
     http: ^0.12.0
   flutter:
     sdk: flutter
   ```
2. Run

   ```sh
   flutter pub get
   ```
3. So it will download all the lib files